# Animating with html5

Tags: html

I saw this great [dynamic image website](http://9elements.com/io/projects/html5/canvas/) which got me curious on actual development.  My plan is to create a friendly more dynamic animation on the left and right margin of the browser giving it more flavor or life. I am a complete beginner but I am willing to learn. So what would I need to create animations like as seen on link and are there any good tutorials to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write raw code for HTML5 canvas or alternatively use a third party app like Adobe Edge.

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/edge/

Also check out CSS3 animations

http://webdesignerwall.com/trends/47-amazing-css3-animation-demos

Or a Javascript animation library like Alice.js

http://blackberry.github.com/Alice/

Answer (score 0):

What you want to learn is HTML5 with Canvas.

Essentially W3 is trying to replace flash with this feature.

Comment: I see so using canvas as the body of an animation but how do you create animations within the canvas? would you need a third party application for it?

Comment: No, there is an entire library of functions related to canvas already apart of HTML5. you use javascript.

Comment: Alright that's enough for me to understand. Canvas and animation didn't seem to make sense to me on html5 reason why I asked the question. Thank you.